# Twofish encryption: "java.security.NosuchAlgorithnException:Twofish KeyGenerator not available" error

Tags: java, twofish

This is the code to generate key for twofish algo and to encrypt using it.

```
SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom(key.getBytes());
KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("twofish");
kg.init(sr);
SecretKey sk = kg.generateKey();

// create an instance of cipher
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("twofish");

// initialize the cipher with the key
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sk);

byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(toEncrypt.getBytes());
```

Comment: Perhaps your security provider does not support Twofish. what provider do you use.

Comment: Also, why use Twofish as opposed to AES? Note that Twofish designer Bruce Schneier uses AES, not Twofish—that is telling.

Comment: Thanks Dear... there is no provider, i am trying to implement it for some comparison purpose..